# FB SDK fql is deprecated for versions v2.1

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I have old C# desktop application which uses FB SDK and FQL query. I have created new FB app and were able to successfully login with my application. However, when I am trying to create an request like:

```
dynamic searchedPosts = await fbClient.GetTaskAsync("/fql", searchParams);
```

I am getting the error:

```
(OAuthException - #12) (#12) fql is deprecated for versions v2.1 and higher
```

To debug this issue I went to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ and populated new Token without anything selected. I've entered FQL query and I am getting the results as expected. If I replace the populated token with the one coming from desktop application I receive an error. Therefore FQL should not be an issue rather an received token. Any idea on why my populated token is different and how to fix it? thx.

Comment: If you just created the Facebook app now, then you can not “downgrade” to any older API version – it will have to use at least the API version that was the “current” one at the time you created your app (which one that is for your app, you can see on the start page of your app dashboard). And that simply means you can not use FQL any more with that app.

Comment: If you have any “old” Facebook app that was created before API v2.1 was introduced, then you could use the app id of that (until that API version gets shut down, and FQL with it) – but further implementing functionality based on FQL _now_ doesn’t make much sense really, that would be “riding a dead horse”. You should rather go and look how you can implement that functionality using the current API.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will defently will upgrade requests... 
I have created new FB user and I've noticed that in Users Apps Settings I have 2 applications : mine and Graph API Explorer. If I use Graph API ID the app is working... any thoughts about that?

Comment: First of all, you are not supposed to create fake accounts for app development – use your own, real, personal account. And secondly, Graph API Explorer app was around during API v2.0 times already, so it might simply still be able to use that version for that reason. And even if that’s not it – it is owned by Facebook, and therefor can have special privileges/capabilities.